# how to create a service layer in my react js app correcly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, clean-architecture

I'm having connection problems with my api in nodejs after I created a service layer in my react app.

This is the folder structure:

```
index.html
└── src
    ├── Components
    │   ├── Pages
    │   │   ├── Home.jsx
    │   │   ├── Provider.jsx
    │   │   ├── login.jsx
    │   │   ├── signup.jsx
    │   │   ...
    │   ├── ProviderComponents
    │   │   ├── WorkListProvider.jsx
    │   │   ...
    ├── Context
    │   └── UserContext.jsx
    └── Services
        └── Api
            ├── authService.js
            ├── config
            │   └── axiosConfig.js
            └── providerService.js
```

`src/Service/Api/config/axiosConfig.js`

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
const token = Cookies.get("token");

// create axios instance
export const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL,
  headers: {
    Authorization : `Bearer ${token}`
  },
});


const errorHandler = (error) => {
  const statusCode = error.response?.status;

  if (statusCode && statusCode !== 401) {
    throw error
  }

  return Promise.reject(error);
};


api.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (error) => {
  return errorHandler(error);
});
```

`src/Service/Api/providerServices`

```
import { api } from "./config/axiosConfig";

export const providerService = {
  getJobs: async () => {
    const response = await api.request({
      url: "/provider/myJobs",
      method: "GET",
    });
    return response.data;
  },
  // other services instances
}
```

call to `providerService` in `src/Components/providerComponents/WorkListProvider.jsx`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  providerService
    .getJobs()
    .then((workList) => {
      setWorkData(workList);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}, []);
```

`src/Service/Api/authService`:

```
import { api } from "./config/axiosConfig";

export const authService = {
  login: async (data) => {
    const response = await api.request({
      url: `/login`,
      data,
      method: "POST",
    });
    console.log(response.data)
    return response.data;
  },
  // other instances services
};
```

use `authServices.login()` in `Login.jsx`

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  authService
    .login(values)
    .then((response) => {
      Cookies.set("token", response.token, { expires: 1 });
      changeLoggedIn(true);
      navigate("/");
    })
    .catch((error) => setErrorMessage(error.response.data.data.error));
};
```

When I login, it returns a 500 error (internal server error) with a 'jwt malformed' message. **But when I refresh the page, it's fixed and i get a correct response from the server**.

Comment: Your `errorHandler` doesn't appear to actually do anything. Are you sure you need it?

Answer (score 0):

Think about the timing of this...

> ```js
> const token = Cookies.get("token");
> ```

How can you use `Cookies.get("token")` before it is set? Secondly, you don't want or need an `Authorization` header for logging in.

I would make two changes...

1. Provide a separate Axios instance for auth requests that excludes the authorization header
2. Move the authorization header to an interceptor so it is calculated at runtime rather than build time.

```js
const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;

export const api = axios.create({ baseURL });
export const authApi = axios.create({ baseURL });

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => ({
  ...config,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get("token")}`,
    ...config.headers,
  },
}), null, { synchronous: true });
```

In `authService`, use the `authApi` instance instead

```js
import { authApi } from "./config/axiosConfig";

export const authService = {
  login: async (data) => {
    const { data } = await authApi.post("/login", data);
    console.log("[authService#login]", data)
    return data;
  },
  // other instances services
};
```